# Doxygen generates empty pages

Tags: treeview, doxygen

I have a page in markdown format with subpages inside.

```
page.md
|
|_\subpage page1 Page1
|_\subpage page2
```

inside page1.md

```
\page page1 PAGE1
  content
```

but when I generate the html output, it creates in the tree view, a empty page1 without content in the main branch of the tree. and another page1 in the correct place with content in the treeview.

How can I get rid of this empty page?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using. where do you see the empty page1 (maybe best to attach image and indicate where you see the empty page).

Comment: @albert I'm using 1.8.5. probably is because of this.

Comment: 1.8.5 ? this is a version released August 23, 2013, I would advise to check whether it is possible to update to the current version (1.8.17). Btw which OS are you using?

Comment: @albert I'm working on RedHat. I tried uptat for last version, but I have to update the GCC, and that is not possible.

Comment: But is 1.8.5 correct?

Comment: @albert yes, currently is 1.8.5

Comment: I did run with a.8.5 as well and see what you mean, whit the current doxygen version (1.8.17) this empty `page1` in the treeview is gone.

Comment: @albert thank you for the info Albert